# How can I convert a JavaScript class to a factory function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a class like this:

```js
class Lazy {
  constructor(iterable, callback) {
    this.iterable = iterable
    this.callback = callback
  }

  filter(callback) {
    return new LazyFilter(this, callback)
  }

  map(callback) {
    return new LazyMap(this, callback)
  }

  next() {
    return this.iterable.next()
  }

  take(n) {
    const values = []
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      values.push(this.next().value)
    }

    return values
  }
}

class LazyFilter extends Lazy {
  next() {
    while (true) {
      const item = this.iterable.next()

      if (this.callback(item.value)) {
        return item
      }
    }
  }
}

class LazyMap extends Lazy {
  next() {
    const item = this.iterable.next()

    const mappedValue = this.callback(item.value)
    return {
      value: mappedValue,
      done: item.done
    }
  }
}
```

This is from a [blog post](https://dev.to/nestedsoftware/lazy-evaluation-in-javascript-with-generators-map-filter-and-reduce--36h5) I came across. It's to lazily create a number list.

I tried to convert the code to factory functions but failed. This is my failed approach:

```js
function Lazy(iterable) {
  const proto = {
    next() {
      return iterable.next();
    },
    take(n) {
      const values = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values.push(proto.next().value);
      }

      return values;
    },
    takeWhile(callback) {
      let result = [];
      let value = this.next().value;
      while (callback(value)) {
        result.push(value);
        value = proto.next().value;
      }
      return result;
    },
    filter(callback) {
      // const that = this
      const next = () => {
        while (true) {
          const item = iterable.next();

          if (callback(item.value)) {
            return item;
          }
        }
      };
      return Object.assign(proto, {
        next
      });
    },
    map(callback) {
      const next = () => {
        const item = iterable.next();

        const mappedValue = callback(item.value);
        return {
          value: mappedValue,
          done: item.done
        };
      };
      return Object.assign(proto, {
        next
      });
    }
  };

  return Object.freeze(Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {
    iterable
  }));
}
```

I don't know what's going wrong here. I am experimenting with factory functions in JavaScript right now, in case you ask why I want to do this.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want the factory function to do?

Comment: @NicholasTower I've updated the code.

Comment: You've still not explained what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your goal is. A factory function is just a function which creates and returns an object, so the simplest factory function for your scenario would just be this:

```
const createInstance = (...args) => new Lazy(...args);
```

If your intention was to remove Lazy altogether, and instead replace it with a factory function that produces object literals, then perhaps something like this is what you're after:

```
const createLazy = (iterable, callback) => {
  return {
    iterable,
    callback,
    filter: function (callback) {
      return createLazyFilter(this, callback)
    }
    // etc for the other functions
  }
}

const createLazyFilter = (iterable, callback) => {
  return Object.assign(createLazy(iterable, callback), {
    next: function () {/* etc */}
  });
};

const createLazyMap = (iterable, callback) => {
  return Object.assign(createLazy(iterable, callback), {
    next: function () {/* etc */}
  });
};
```